# locust : hooks -> run a custom code with locust performance testing environment

Tags: python-3.x, locust

I am trying to run a code during the load testing is happening(eg push aggregated data to database).

I am using locust ***init event handler*** --> https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html#locust.event.Events.init

Here is my code:

[image]

***process_exit_code*** value is always ***None***, event locust has finish the load test.

Is there any way that we can run a custom code like this during the time locust is performing the performance testing ?

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

`process_exit_code` is only used for *overriding* the normal exit code. It is never set by Locust internally, and not intended to be read by the user.

If you want to do something particular at locust shut down, use the quitting event instead: https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/running-locust-without-web-ui.html#controlling-the-exit-code-of-the-locust-process

There is another problem with your code: because your while loop never sleeps, it will not allow anything else to run (like your User).

Comment: Hi @Cyberwiz  Thanks, The provided link help me to fix my issue. Thanks for showing my mistake. 
Further, is it possible to access the instance of environment class  with the request_failure or request_success handlers . Because I am looking a way to dynamically update(current rps & current users ) in my influxDB Table. Please help